# Bamboo Grunt 'dustc' task failing

Tags: gruntjs, npm, bamboo, dust.js, dustc

I've moved my grunt job into Bamboo and everything works great except for the dust compiler.  All of my other tasks in my gruntfile can be targeted from the bamboo task and they work.  The `dustc` task gives this error when run: `Fatal error: Error: not found: dustc`.

I've manually run the `dustc` task on the build machine's command prompt every way I know how and it works.  I even copied the command from the Bamboo build log - the one it uses to execute the grunt task - and it works just fine.

I just can't get it to work when I run the build from within Bamboo.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what does the code look like?

Comment: is this windows or linux? Local or remote agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a permissions/visibility issue.

Evidently system users (or at least the one which was running my build service) don't have access to the system environment variables in Windows.  Learn something new every day!

I created a user to run the service (which I probably should have done in the first place) and that non-system user was able to see the correct PATH settings.

This took care of the problem.